# Delphi: refer to a component from multiple frames

Tags: delphi, vcl

I want to refer to a component (using loop) which exists in multiple frames. The component is the same for all frames.

- I have a ComboBox named "comboBoxAccount".
- I also have multiple frames (which I instantiate at runtime).
  The frames I create are named:

  frm1, frm2, frm3
- Each frame has a multple TabSheets created at runtime named:
  page_1, page_2, page_3

So, I am currently using:
`Tfrm1(FindComponent('page_'+i)).comboBoxAccount`

Which means I use `FindComponent` with i in a loop to access all `comboBoxAccount` in all TabSheets.

The problem is that I have to use casting to make Delphi understand which component I want to access, so I've put `Tfrm1( )` in front of `FindComponent`.

So, if I want to use casting with a loop what can I do?

I could just use:

```
Tfrm1(FindComponent('page_'+i)).comboBoxAccount
Tfrm2(FindComponent('page_'+i)).comboBoxAccount
Tfrm3(FindComponent('page_'+i)).comboBoxAccount
```

but is there a way to loop `Tfrm` without writing them one by one?

Comment: Please show your actual compilable code

Comment: There are too many parts that invole my problem here and it would take many lines of code. My main issue is:

Is there a way to access controls from frames which are instantiated at runtime?

There are TabSheets, for each TabSheets there are multiple TabSheets (created at runtime) and inside each child TabSheet there is a frame with the control I want to access.

Can I used tags? Or any way to access controls of controls (TabSheets inside Tabsheets)?

Comment: Ok. Don't give us any context then. But don't expect on topic help.

Comment: It's not that I dont want to give my code, I just have to rewrite it in an understandable way so it will take some time. Maybe today I will finish it. Would it be rather better to put 350+ lines of code? Cause if I dont rewrite it  and put just the functions here, it would take that amount of code lines my friend..

Comment: Read this [mcve]. Personally I would never call FindComponent. Why don't you just remember the controls that you need to work with. Put them in a container. Don't ever use unsafe casts like that. Use a type checked cast.

Comment: Why not add whatever you want to do to comboBoxAccount as a procedure or function of the frame? Then you get good segregation, and you could iterate through your frames very easily (assuming one frame per tab). You can even use polymorphism to iterate through different frame types provided that they are descended from the same base frame type that implements these procedures and functions.

Answer (score 1):

`page_1`, `page_2`, etc are TabSheets, not frames, but you are casting them to frames, which is wrong.

If each frame has multiple TabSheets on it, and each TabSheet has a ComboBox on it, you would not use `FindComponent()` at all.  You would have to iterate through parent/child [`Controls[]`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.Controls) lists instead, or use [`FindChildControl()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.FindChildControl).

However, if the frame is the `Owner` of the ComboBox (which it would be if the ComboBox is added to the frame at design-time), then you would use `FindComponent()` on the frame itself. But you cannot have multiple child components with the same name, so each ComboBox on each TabSheet would need a unique name:

```pascal
cb := TComboBox(frm1.FindComponent('comboBoxAccount_'+IntToStr(i)));
```

Repeating for each index of `frm1`, then all indexes of `frm2`, then `frm3`.

If your ComboBox really is named just `comboBoxAccount` then I wonder if you really have one parent container that has multiple TabSheets on it, and each TabSheet has a frame on it, and each frame has only one ComboBox named `comboBoxAccount` on it. If that is the case, you don't need to do any searching at all, just use your existing object pointers directly:

```pascal
cb :=  frm1.comboBoxAccount;
cb :=  frm2.comboBoxAccount;
cb :=  frm3.comboBoxAccount;
```

But if you really want to use a loop, then put the frames into a list,  eg:

```pascal
private
    Frames: TList;

...

Frames := TList.Create;
Frames.Add(frm1);
Frames.Add(frm2);
Frames.Add(frm3);

...

for I := 0 to Frames.Count-1 do
begin
  // assuming TFrm1, TFrm2, etc do not have a common ancestor holding the ComboBox...
  cb := TComboBox(TWinControl(Frames[i]).FindComponent('comboBoxAccount'));
  ...
end;
```

Or use an array:

```pascal
private
  // assuming TFrm1, TFrm2, etc do not have a common ancestor holding the ComboBox...
  Frames: array[0..2] of TWinControl;

...

Frames[0] := frm1;
Frames[1] := frm2;
Frames[2] := frm3;

...

for I := Low(Frames) to High(Frames) do
begin
  cb := TComboBox(Frames[i].FindComponent('comboBoxAccount'));
  ...
end;
```

---

**Update**: given new information you provided, you can find the ComboBox like this instead:

```pascal
cb := Tfrm1(PageControl[i].Pages[j].FindChildControl('frame_'+IntToStr(i))).comboBoxAccount;
```

Your `while` loop is creating multiple tabsheets and frames that have the same `Name`, which is not valid.  I would suggest not naming them at all.

```pascal
while condition=true do
begin
  TabSheet := TTabSheet.Create(PageControl[i]);
  TabSheet.Caption := '';
  //TabSheet.Name:='tabesheet_'+IntToStr(i);
  TabSheet.PageControl := PageControl[i];
  TabSheet.PageControl.ActivePageIndex:=0;
  {I also create a frame for each TabSheet. In every frame there is the     ComboBox that I want to access}
  frame := Tfrm1.Create(TabSheet);
  //frame.Name:='frame_'+IntToStr(i);
  frame.Parent:=TabSheet;
end;
```

Assuming a frame is the only child of its TabSheet, you can then do this:

```pascal
cb := Tfrm1(PageControl[i].Pages[j].Controls[0]).comboBoxAccount;
```

Comment: Thank you for all your advises my friend. I will study your answer and try different thing around. I will try to put each frame on a List and loop through.

Each comboBox is inside a frame (I've put it in design-time) so there is no unique name for each comboBox. 

Is there a way to iterate through every single control of the form (childs and even childs of childs) and find the combobox using tags maybe.

Comment: @ConstantinosKarentzos I already addressed that on my answer.